# auto animated scroll down using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to make an animated scroll to a bottom button using jQuery that fades out when the page is located at the bottom. I have found this code on the internet and modified it, but I could not get it work.

```
 <script>
    //to bottom
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // hide #back-top first

        $("#back-bottom").show();

        // fade in #back-top
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop()  1) {
                    $('#back-bottom').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#back-bottom').show();
                }
            });

            // scroll body to 0px on click
            $('#back-bottom a').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you show your html markup too

Comment: Create a fiddle for this please so people can see what's going wrong exactly. It's hard to guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to calculate body height and pass that to the scrollTop parameter in the animate

```
$('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').height() }, 800);
```

<del>[Check here the working demo]</del> // Link has stopped working

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it and please do give me that demo link

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#back-bottom a').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').height() }, 500);
                return false;
            });
```

i think it will work for you

Comment: Should work for scrolling to the bottom, but there was also an error in the code for showing the button when not at the bottom.

Comment: thanks soo much it works great howerever 2 problems 1 it does not scroll smooth and 2 it does not fade out please tell me how to achive that thanks

Comment: first think u needed is smooth scroll for that 500 increase to 1000 or how much u needed depending upon that

Comment: for fade out use this code $('#back-bottom a').fadeOut('slow'); (after this code use fade out code $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').height() }, 500);
 )

Answer (score 0):

Created an example fiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5JNc/

Changed the condition to hide the button to: `if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())`

To scroll back to the top, added a variable that gets the height of the body:
`var $elem = $('body')`
Then when the link is clicked, changed the value to be:
`scrollTop: $elem.height()`